# Java addShutdownHook method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int [] intArray = new int[500]; 
        SomeThread t1 = new SomeThread(intArray,0,99,1);
        SomeThread t2 = new SomeThread(intArray,100,200,2); 
            t1.run();
            System.exit(0);

            Thread hook = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    if(!t1.isReady){
                        t1.run();
                    }
                    else if(!t2.isReady){
                        System.out.println("Code reached here ------");
                        t2.run();
                    }
                }
            };
            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(hook);
          }
```

Basically I have an array which is manipulated by two different threads. Inside the threads there is a boolean variabla `isReady` that checks whether the thread has finished its job properly. On purpose I didnt start the second thread, just to check whether it will execute after the System.exit() but the code never reaches there. I just want to run the second thread just before closing the JVM. I put also the System.exit() just to test the application whether it will do something just before closing it.

Update: the question is why the code never reaches the second if statement, I checked the isReady variable is false:/

Comment: why the code never reaches the second if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the hook before calling `System.exit()`. The way your code is written now, the part where you set the hook will never actually be evaluated.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks, I will accept the answer in 6 mins